# python function with arguments assigned to a variable

Tags: python, function, arguments

I have a function

```
def x(whatever):
    ....
```

I want to assign

```
y = x(whatever)
```

So that I can pass around y to a wrapper which then calls the method that y refers to. The problem is that each type of function x can have variable arguments. Is it possible to do this in python, assigning y = x(whatever) and then pass around y as a parameter.

I tried y = x(whatever) and passed around y to the wrapper which then did

```
ret = y() # dict object is not callable
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I *think* you are looking for [`functools.partial()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial

y = partial(x, whatever)
```

When `y` is called, `x(whatever)` is called.

You can achieve the same with a `lambda`:

```
y = lambda: x(whatever)
```

but a `partial()` accepts additional arguments, which will be passed on to the wrapped callable.

Comment: One other difference: the callable returned by `partial` fixes the argument to the value of `whatever` at that time. The callable returned by `lambda` uses the current value of `whatever` when it is called.

Comment: @chepner: That is true; the same applies to `x`. You can use `lambda x=x, w=whatever: x(w)` to bind both to the lambda.